# Autenticar con JWT

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

estoy tratando de autenticar mi usuario y contraseña con Jwt en ASP.NET Core pero me devuelve error al ejecutarlo con Postman , ya creé mi cadena de conexión y lo mande llamar en mi startup , tambien creé mi modelo UserModel y mi controlador LoginController en el cual esta todo mi método¿en donde estoy fallando?¿qué error estoy cometiendo? quisiera probar para luego poder conectarlo con mi base de datos y probar con datos reales

**esta es mi cadena de conexión**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "Jwt": {
    "Key": "AshProgHelpSecretKey",
    "Issuer": "ashproghelp.com"
  }
}
```

**este es mi startup**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JwtPrueba
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JwtPrueba", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().Build());
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "JwtPrueba v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**este es mi modelo**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JWTAuthDemo.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**este es mi controlador**

```
using JWTAuthDemo.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JWTAuthDemo.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;

        public LoginController (IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string username,string pass)
        {
            UserModel login = new UserModel();
            login.UserName = username;
            login.Password = pass;
            IActionResult response = Unauthorized();

            var user = AuthenticateUser(login);

            if(user !=null)
            {
                var tokenStr = GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
                response = Ok(new { token = tokenStr });
            }

            return response;
        }
        private UserModel AuthenticateUser(UserModel login)
        {
            UserModel user = null;
            if(login.UserName=="ashproghelp" && login.Password == "123")
            {
                user = new UserModel { UserName = "AshprogHelp", EmailAddres = "ashproghelp@gmail.com", Password = "123" };
            }
            return user;
        }

        private string GenerateJSONWebToken(UserModel userinfo)
        {
            var securutyKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securutyKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,userinfo.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email,userinfo.EmailAddres),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(

                issuer: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
                signingCredentials: credentials);

            var encodetoken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return encodetoken;
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("Post")]
        public string Post()
        {
            var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            IList<Claim> claim = identity.Claims.ToList();
            var userName = claim[0].Value;
            return "BInevenido :" + userName;
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("GetValue")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
        }
    }
}
```

**error que genera en postman**

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1",
    "title": "Unauthorized",
    "status": 401,
    "traceId": "00-e5297a6378850547b2d1f6b413649999-bec907f814c9bb4d-00"
}
```

**imagen postman**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y donde esta el error que comentas?

Comment: @JuanRivera ya lo agregué a la pregunta

Comment: Has hardcodeado la contraseña como `123`, has probado a imprimir en pantalla la contraseña que recibe tu endpoint?

Comment: si , normal no tiene error @Benito-B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la llamada.

Al utilizar el método GET no deberías incluir los parámetros en el body de la petición, si no en la url como query string.

Además, la acción espera un parámetro con nombre `pass` y en la llamada estás utilizando una propiedad `Password`.

La url debería ser:

https://localhost:44374/api/Login?username=ashproghelp&pass=123

Aunque así te va a funcionar, no es una práctica recomendable utilizar GET para enviar datos como contraseñas, ya que se envían en plano y es muy fácil de interceptar. Mejor utiliza una acción con método POST.

Para ello simplemente cambia el atributo de la acción por `HttpPost` y haz que reciba como parámetro directamente un objeto `UserModel`. Marca ese parámetro con el atributo `FromBody` para que asp.net lo busque en el cuerpo de la petición:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login([FromBody] UserModel login)
    {
        IActionResult response = Unauthorized();

        var user = AuthenticateUser(login);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var tokenStr = GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
            response = Ok(new { token = tokenStr });
        }

        return response;
    }
```

En la petición de Postman utiliza el método POST en lugar de GET y pásale, como estabas haciendo, la información de login en el cuerpo de la solicitud:

[image: Petición Postman]

PD. Aunque no tiene nada que ver, y no vas a tener ningún problema por ello, llamas dos veces al método `AddControllers` en el Startup.

Comment: como seria el código para que sea como post? disculpe la molestia , soy principiante

Comment: Edito la respuesta para añadir cómo implementar la petición POST

Comment: si , por favor si no es molestia

Comment: Maestro una ayuda mas por favor

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el primer claim en `GenerateJSONWebToken()`

```
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, request.UserName)
```

Por

```
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, request.UserName)
```

Y/O tienes que decirle a la autorización que quieres usar Jwt

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```